# R - Using str_split and unlist to create two columns

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a dataset that has dates and interest rates in the same column. I need to split these two numbers into two separate columns, however when I use the following code:

```
 Split <- str_split(df$Dates, "[ ]", n = 2)
 Dates <- unlist(Split)[1]
 Rates <- unlist(Split)[2]
```

It returns only the first "value" of each element, i.e., "1971-04-01" for Dates and "7.43" for Rates. I need it to return all values for the portion of the string split and the same for the second portion of the string split

Below is a portion of the dataset, total rows = 518.

```
    1971-04-01   7.31
    1971-05-01   7.43
    1971-06-01   7.53
    1971-07-01   7.60
    1971-08-01   7.70
    1971-09-01   7.69
    1971-10-01   7.63
    1971-11-01   7.55
    1971-12-01   7.48
    1972-01-01   7.44
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could do

```
Split <- strsplit(as.character(df$Dates), " ", fixed = TRUE)
Dates <- sapply(Split, "[", 1)
Rates <- sapply(Split, "[", 2)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, though I had to use 4 for Rates, due to it picking up 4 separate splits. When I used str_split, I was able to specify the number of actual splits to make, if I didn't it picked up the same number of splits. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `reshape2::colsplit`

```
library(reshape2)
colsplit(df$Dates, ' ', names =  c('Dates','Rates'))
#         Dates Rates
# 1  1971-04-01  7.31
# 2  1971-05-01  7.43
# 3  1971-06-01  7.53
# 4  1971-07-01  7.60
# 5  1971-08-01  7.70
# 6  1971-09-01  7.69
# 7  1971-10-01  7.63
# 8  1971-11-01  7.55
# 9  1971-12-01  7.48
# 10 1972-01-01  7.44
```

Comment: Now you can also look at `tidyr::separate()` that does the same thing

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm biased, but I would suggest [my **`cSplit`** function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) for this problem.

First, I'm assuming we are starting with the following (single column) `data.frame` (where there are multiple spaces between the "date" value and the "rate" value).

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("1971-04-01   7.31", "1971-05-01   7.43", "1971-06-01   7.53", 
           "1971-07-01   7.60", "1971-08-01   7.70", "1971-09-01   7.69", 
           "1971-10-01   7.63", "1971-11-01   7.55", "1971-12-01   7.48", 
           "1972-01-01   7.44"))
```

Next, [get the `cSplit` function from my GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733), and use it. You can split on a regular expression (here, multiple spaces).

```
cSplit(df, "Date", "\\s+", fixed = FALSE)
#         Date_1 Date_2
#  1: 1971-04-01   7.31
#  2: 1971-05-01   7.43
#  3: 1971-06-01   7.53
#  4: 1971-07-01   7.60
#  5: 1971-08-01   7.70
#  6: 1971-09-01   7.69
#  7: 1971-10-01   7.63
#  8: 1971-11-01   7.55
#  9: 1971-12-01   7.48
# 10: 1972-01-01   7.44
```

Since the function converts a `data.frame` to a `data.table`, you have access to `setnames` which would let you rename your columns in place.

```
setnames(cSplit(df, "Date", "\\s+", fixed = FALSE), c("Dates", "Rates"))[]
#          Dates Rates
#  1: 1971-04-01  7.31
#  2: 1971-05-01  7.43
#  3: 1971-06-01  7.53
#  4: 1971-07-01  7.60
#  5: 1971-08-01  7.70
#  6: 1971-09-01  7.69
#  7: 1971-10-01  7.63
#  8: 1971-11-01  7.55
#  9: 1971-12-01  7.48
# 10: 1972-01-01  7.44
```

Comment: I actually ended up using a concat.split as I had to do this for numerous files of a similar set-up. I was running into errors due to slight spacing issues from the files; nothing like government datasets to be clean and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using @user2583119's data (please post minimal reproducible code including a data set):

```
library(qdap)
colsplit2df(data.frame(Split), sep = " ")

##           X1   X2
## 1 1971-06-01 7.53
## 2 1971-05-01 7.43
## 3 1971-06-01 7.53
```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
 Split <- c("1971-06-01 7.53", "1971-05-01 7.43", "1971-06-01 7.53")
```

Your code selects only the first observation.

```
 Str <- unlist(str_split(Split, "[ ]", n=2))
 Str[1] 
 #[1] "1971-06-01"
```

If you look at the `output` of unlist(..), dates are followed by values.  So, you can use a logical index.

```
Str[c(T,F)]
#[1] "1971-06-01" "1971-05-01" "1971-06-01"

as.numeric(Str[c(F,T)])
#[1] 7.53 7.43 7.53
```

You can convert to two columns of a dataframe from `Split` by using `read.table`

```
  read.table(text=Split, header=F, sep="",stringsAsFactors=F)
 #         V1   V2
 # 1 1971-06-01 7.53
 # 2 1971-05-01 7.43
 # 3 1971-06-01 7.53
```

Comment: +1. I personally use the `read.table` trick quite a bit, and used it in my "splitstackshape" package. However, because there are faster options than `read.table`, I've been playing around with creating different functions, like [`cSplit`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) and [`concat.split.DT`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058).

Comment: Thanks `Ananda Mahto` for the functions.  It would be better to have `cSplit` in a package.

Comment: It's planned--just haven't gotten around to testing whether everything really seems OK for committing it to the "splitstackshape" package. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(
Date = c("1971-04-01   7.31", "1971-05-01   7.43", "1971-06-01   7.53", 
         "1971-07-01   7.60", "1971-08-01   7.70", "1971-09-01   7.69", 
         "1971-10-01   7.63", "1971-11-01   7.55", "1971-12-01   7.48", 
         "1972-01-01   7.44"))

do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$Date), split = '\\s+', fixed = FALSE))
```

Comment: please give more clarifications.refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Split <- c("1971-06-01 7.53", "1971-05-01 7.43", "1971-06-01 7.53")
df <- unlist(str_split(string = Split, pattern = "\\s"))
df
```